# mfc probelm in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to make mfc simple project to my final assignment in oop course, but after I install the mfc
I get error of:

`1. STRCPY_S`

The file that have the error is read only and I can't change it. I've tried to add `CRT` comment and change the precomplier but no result.

[error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AedE9.png)

- the line is gives the error:

  ```
  inline void __cdecl strcpy_s(
  _Out_writes_z_(_S1max) char *_S1,
  _In_ size_t _S1max,
  _In_z_ const char *_S2)
  ```

  {
      ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::strcpy_s(_S1, _S1max, _S2));
  }

---

Comment: The problem isn't in the standard library so it must be either in your project configuration or build system. Can you post a picture of your project configuration in VS?

Comment: do you mean to this one? https://imgur.com/a/GDUDOoy

Comment: No. The `C/C++` and `Linker` ones would be ideal.

Comment: Hope this is it  https://imgur.com/qmnmW3P